# Label convert findcontrol

Tags: c#, gridview, casting, label

I am not very experienced and perhaps I am asking a stupid question. I'm trying to delete a row inside this gridview. To do this, I call a method `deleteDettagliDocument(id_row)` to perform a `DELETE` from my DB. This method takes an integer as parameter but the control is a Label and I can't cast it properly. Here's my code.

```
protected void grdContact_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    bool result;
    DboDocument objdbo = new DboDocument();
    InvoiceDetails ID = new InvoiceDetails();
    List<InvoiceDetails> app = (List<InvoiceDetails>)Session["lst_details"];
    int id_row = (Label)grdContact.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId_Row"); // Error!
    app.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    Session["lst_details"] = app;
    FillGrid();
    CalculateTotal();
    result = objdbo.deleteDocumentDetails(id_row);
}
```

Comment: You cannot convert a `Label` into an `int`. You probably want to convert the `Label`'s text property into an int?

Comment: Is the int `id` stored on the label or something? A more common approach would be to save this to a hidden field. But the reason you're getting an error is because you're trying to assign a `Label` type to an `int`. You need to get the value out of it, something like: `Convert.ToInt32((Label)grdContact.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId_Row").Text);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign `Label` to `int`,

```
Label lbl = grdContact.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId_Row") as Label;
if(lbl != null)
{
   int id_row = int.Parse(lbl.Text);
}
```